# Throwing an error/pop up on record and need to save it in salesforce

Tags: case, error-messages

On case object we have a field Delivery Number(Text) whenever user enters that value if that number is duplicate. We need to show pop-up/error message (basically inform user) that it is already exists and should get saved in salesforce.

Validation rules,Triggers,Unique field checked are all prevent the record saving in salesforce.In this case i want to save it in salesforce.

So i have tried a trigger and apex class.

Trigger :

```
trigger trgr_Case_DuplicateCheck on Case(before Insert, before Update) {
    new DuplicateCase().checkDuplicates(trigger.new);
}
```

Apex  Class:

```
public class DuplicateCase{
    private Apexpages.Standardcontroller controller;

    public void checkDuplicates(List<Case> lstCase){


        Map<String, Id> mapCase= new Map<String, Id>();

        Set<String> setCase = new Set<String>();
        for(Case ca: lstCase)
            setCase .add(ca.Delivery__C);

         for(Case c : lstCase)
            setCase .add(c.CaseNumber);


        for(
            Case ca:
            [
                SELECT Id, Delivery__c FROM Case WHERE  Delivery__C IN : setCase 
            ]
        )
            mapCase.put(ca.Delivery__c, ca.Id);

            for(
            Case c:
            [
                SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE  Delivery__C IN : setCase 
            ]
        )

            mapCase.put(c.CaseNumber, c.Id);


        for(Case ca: lstCase)
            if(
                mapCase.containsKey(ca.Delivery__c) &&
                mapCase.get(ca.Delivery__c) != ca.Id
            )
                ca.addError(
                    'The case '+ca.CaseNumber+' has already same Delivery number'   ,
                    true
                                      );   
    }


}
```

Comment: addErorr doesn't work? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you move to the declarative functionality Salesforce provide for duplicate detection. You can use [Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) to create Duplicate Rules. For each Duplicate Rule, you can have many Matching Rules.

> Duplicate Rule: Can block users from saving records that have been
>   identified as possible duplicates, or simply alert users that they may
>   be creating a duplicate, but allow them to save the record anyway.
>
> Matching Rule: Can specify that if the Email and Phone values of two
>   records match exactly, the records might be duplicates.

The following is an example of a Duplicate Rule where I am preventing the Save action from executing by notifying the User of a duplicate and giving them an option to continue with Save or to use the existing record. This works well with fields that are key identifiers of a record such as SSN or Employee ID.
[image]

The Matching Rule that is used in the Duplicate Rule is as follows.

[image]

And the warning message that is displayed when a duplicate is detected looks like:

[image]

Don't forget to activate both your Duplicate Rule and Matching Rule before attempting to test, can catch you out!

Comment: Feature is not available for Cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a native Salesforce feature called [Duplicate Management](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_sales_duplicate_management_intro.htm). It's a no-code solution for your problem. Check this [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) for mor information.

It also states:

> Users can click Save (ignore alert) on the comparison page when
>   manually cleaning a record to ignore duplicate alerts and save the
>   record.

So it would perfectly fit your needs.

### EDIT:

Unfortunately it is not available for Cases (yet) but there is already an idea: [Duplicate Management for Cases](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjN5AAK)

Comment: Is matching Rule is available for case also ? I am not pretty sure about this so.

Comment: @NITHESHK thanks for your comment, I double checked an it is not :( but there is an idea, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display an alert from a trigger -- a trigger doesn't have any direct access to the user interface. You could instead write a logic in that trigger itself to insert a "case comment" which says "Duplicate Number".

Just after you  save the record in your trigger, you can use the following code to insert a case comment on the respective case.

```
CaseComment newComment = new CaseComment();
newComment.CommentBody = "Duplicate Number";
newComment.IsPublished = TRUE;
newComment.ParentId = case.id;
insert newComment;
```

[Also go through the link which has similar discussion in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595574/display-alert-box-through-the-trigger-salesforce)

[How to display a message when the trigger finishes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23656/how-to-display-a-message-when-the-trigger-finishes)